# How to wait for an element and click using name attribute

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the below html mark-up I am trying to access and click via python... for some reason copying the xpath and doing this is **not** working:

```
self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*`[@id="isc_8D"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/img')`
```

It seems the 'name' attribute is the only unique identifier below; how could I WAIT for it to exist first, then find element by name attribute and click in python? i.e.  **name="isc_NXicon"**

```
<img src="http://website:8080/DBWEBSITE/ui/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/TabSet/close.png" width="12" height="12" align="absmiddle" style="vertical-align:middle" name="isc_NXicon" eventpart="icon" border="0" suppress="TRUE" draggable="true">
```

I am doing the below via different element with CSS selector: But **How could I do the same via html 'name attribute' for my current relevant mark-up?**

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-mini.btn-primary"))).click()
```

Comment: Did you look at [the docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)? What did you find? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

To locate and `click()` on the desired element instead of using `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to use *WebDriverWait* for the **`element_to_be_clickable()`** and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[name='isc_NXicon'][src$='DBWEBSITE/ui/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/TabSet/close.png']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@name='isc_NXicon' and contains(@src, 'DBWEBSITE/ui/sc/skins/Enterprise/images/TabSet/close.png')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```